# Как сделать таймер в Android

Tags: java, android, android-threads, android-handler

Всем добрый день, пишу свое приложение и в нем есть таймер. Раньше я делал это через `Handler`. С помощью метода post обновлял и смотрел время, а в время засекал через `System.currentTimeMillis()`, но это был секундомер, сейчас мне понадобился таймер, хотел пойти тем же путем, но мне кажется это не эффективный и не правильный способ. Подскажите пожалуйста, что лучше использовать для таймера.

Comment: делайте через handler.post( ..., 1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуглится на раз два.

Вот несколько вариантов, выбирай:

[`TimerTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask)

[`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

[`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Вот пример `CountDownTimer`

```java
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
 }.start();
```

Comment: Я просто в шоке, насколько все просто оказалось. Я явно не умею гуглить, спасибо.